# Concatenate string values with delimiter handling null and empty strings?

Tags: java, java-8, guava, apache-stringutils

In Java 8 I have some number of `String` values and I want to end up with a comma delimited list of valid values.  If a `String` is **null or empty** I want to ignore it.  I know this seems common and is a lot like [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642159/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-concatenate-a-list-of-values-with-delimiter-in-ja); however, that discussion does not address nulls AND spaces (I also don't like the accepted answer).

I've looked at Java 8 `StringJoiner`, Commons `StringUtils` (`join`) and trusty Guava (`Joiner`) but none seems like a full solution.  The vision:

```
 where: val1 = "a", val2 = null, val3 = "", val4 = "b"

  String niceString = StringJoiner.use(",").ignoreBlanks().ignoreNulls()
    .add(val1).add(val2).add(val3).add(val4).toString();
```

...would result in `niceString` = `a,b`

Isn't there a nice way to do this (that doesn't involve for loops, loading strings into a list, and/or regex replaces to remove bad entries)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380784/java-8-stream-string-null-or-empty-filter

Comment: The straightforward java 8 way is `Stream.of(val1, val2, val3, val4).filter(s -> s!=null && !s.isEmpty()).collect(joining(","))` with a static import of `Collectors.joining`.  If that's not to your liking, you would have to make your own class or find one in some library.  But why bother?

Comment: dup by title perhaps but not intension.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35570259/5191913) answer in Java 8 not do exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: Users need to get the idea that a duplicate is bad out of their heads. If a solution exists, we should point to it instead of splitting up the knowledge everywhere.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

```
String joined = 
    Stream.of(val1, val2, val3, val4)
          .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
          .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: There are quite a few related and duplicate questions. Please vote to close as such and provide your answers there if they apply.

Comment: @Pillar questions answered by Brian Goetz (one of main Java architects) automatically become questions which others should use as duplicate target (he is our Jon Skeet of Java 8).

Comment: @Brian what happens if all of var1, var2... are null?

Comment: @OptimusPrime The delimiter passed to `joining()` is a separator.  If all the elements are null, they all get filtered, so the stream presented to `collect()` is empty.  In that case, you'll get an empty string out.  There are alternate versions of `joining()` that let you specify prefix and suffix too, in which case you'd get `prefix + suffix`.

Comment: Can I somehow get null instead of the empty string?

Comment: Yes, just use `collectingAndThen()` with a finishing function that maps `""` to `null`.

Comment: `Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): java.util.stream.Stream` in Android

Comment: Might be even more readable by using Stringutils to check if the String is null or empty `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s)` within the filter