# Remove Null from For loop of ArrayList

Tags: java, sql, arrays, sqlite, arraylist

I am currently converting an ArrayList to a String to send it to a DB so I can retrieve it on the other end and convert it back to an ArrayList later.

My thought process is to convert it to a string currently by doing the following

```
for(Integer o: questions) questionString += o + ",";
```

`questions` is the ArrayList and looks like this: `[4, 4]`

When I look at my database it looks like this `null4,4,`

How would I go about removing `null` at the start and the last `,` so it looks like `4,4` on the  database?

On the other end I can then get it by using the following:

`ArrayList myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayQuestions.split(",")));`

( I am using SQLite which is a requirement for my college project )

Comment: Hint: do you know how to check whether something is null? (`if (o == null)` in this case, or `if (o != null)` to test whether it's not null.) I'd also strongly recommend *always* using braces for loops, as an aside.

Comment: Well, why not having a table that will keep each element of your list in a single row? Give more details on what you want to do so we can guide you. Show the project question.

Comment: @Tarik Sorry, it's a quiz project.  We have to give the user two attempts at quiz so to get the questions from the previous quiz im storing the question_ID's in an ArrayList to be stored in the DB but I found out SQLite doesn't let you use setArray().

My thought process is to store them as a String so on the other end I can parse them back into an ArrayList

Comment: This looks like it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705880/concatenate-string-values-with-delimiter-handling-null-and-empty-strings

Comment: Store them one by one in a table with a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `questionString` to "" before the loop;

```
String questionString = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if "o" is null.

```
if (o == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using SQL (SQLite specifically). That means you should avoid storing an ArrayList as a String.

Instead, you want to look into database normalization and the relational model. Rather than having a single row with a list in it, you should use multiple rows for each list element.